# Parse email reply quotes using regexp

Tags: php, regex, email

I have a PHP script that deals with emails, I'd like to catch strings like this one:

```
>> John replied with a nice hi...
>> then added a second hi...
>
>> Ray said hello
```

Note the 3rd line contains only `>` instead of `>>`

and `normalise it`, ie. transform it into:

```
>> John replied with a nice hi...
>> then added a second hi...
>>
>> Ray said hello
```

In other words, I'd like to catch **non-empty lines** which starts with `>` & replace them with `>>`

My question may look worthless, but I have a nice regexp that takes these `>` & format them nicely, ie.

```
>> John replied with a nice hi...
>> then added a second hi...
>>
>> Ray said hello
```

becomes

```
[quote]
    John replied with a nice hi...
    then added a second hi...

    Ray said hello
[/quote]
```

The scenario above *breaks* my formatting & makes the final output looks like this:

```
[quote_level_1]
    John replied with a nice hi...
    then added a second hi...
[/quote_level_1]

[quote_level_2]
[/quote_level_2]

[quote_level_1]
    Ray said hello
[/quote_level_1]
```

**My question is** Is there a regexp I can use to handle this situation? I tried **many** regular expressions, none of them gave me correct results :(

I'm using **PHP 5.4**

### EDIT

I'm afraid I didn't formulate my question accurately (sorry about that), what I want is to catch **non-empty lines** which starts with `>` & replace them with `>>`, but **only if the line in question is located between 2 non-empty lines which starts with `>>`**

I hope I clarified my question, sorry!

Comment: Do you actually want to remove line with just one '>', since you already have regex to match it?

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to catch non-empty lines which starts with > and replace them with >>

That regex looks like this:

```
/^>(?=[^>])/m
```

Where the `/` is the delimiter, `^` matches the beginning of the line (because we specified multi-line mode with the `m` modifier), and then specify that we must match *something* that isn't a `>` after the first `>`.

You would use it in PHP like this:

```
preg_replace( '/^>(?=[^>])/m', '>>', $str)
```

And you can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/v9z8o1) that this prints:

```
>> John replied with a nice hi...
>> then added a second hi...
>>
>> Ray said hello
```

Comment: Thank you nickb! This is a nice start, but I only want to catch the lines that are "hiding" between two other `>> lines`. I edited my question to clarify - my apologies for not being more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

This seems to be a straightforward regexp application.

```
$normalized_text = preg_replace("/^>(.+)/m", ">>${1}", $your_text);
```

Comment: Thanks! but I only want to catch lines "hiding" between two other `>>-lines`. I edited my question to clarify - my apologies for not being more explicit.